# Div don't reposition when browser is resized

Tags: html, css

```
<h3 style="text-align: center">NOT THIS</h3>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <div style="background-color: brown; width: 200px; height: 10px; display: block; margin: auto;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: grey; width: 100px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; margin-right: -4px;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: grey; width: 100px; height: 50px; display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>

<br>

<h3 style="text-align: center">BUT LIKE THIS</h3>
<div style="background-color: brown; width: 200px; height: 10px; display: block; margin: auto;"></div>
<div style="margin: auto; background-color: grey; width: 200px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Please watch example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/17h1oj3e/

When I resize width of my browser, 2 divs of first part of code are repositioning.

Do you know how to get same of SECOND PART results on first two divs with center align and automatic margin?

Thank you very very much

Answer (score 1):

Ass `white-space: nowrap` on the parent div.

```html
<div style="text-align: center; white-space:nowrap;">
  <div style="background-color: brown; width: 200px; height: 10px; display: block; margin: auto;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: grey; width: 100px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; margin-right: -4px;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: grey; width: 100px; height: 50px; display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if this helps but, you could use flexbox.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .flexbox{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        font-size: 16px;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .bar{
        background: brown;
        height: 10px;
    }
    .half{
        background: grey;
        padding: 3rem;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .half:last-of-type{
        background: lightgrey;
    }
    .flexbox-nowrap{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="flexbox-nowrap">
        <div class="half">hello</div>
        <div class="half">world</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, this code is responsive, so it works in all display sizes

Comment: Thank you very much, I saw this is not totally compatible with all browsers

Comment: I found a way to go around the problem, making a single div and put inside a new div (not two separate)

Comment: Actually, if you check this page https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox you can see that flexbox is alredy all the browsers. the problem could be that not ALL versions of the browsers stands it. But believe me, is better than you be updated instead of your clients. Less than 10% use older versions.

Comment: You're welcome bro. Lets create the Internet a better place

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: block; margin: auto; background: brown; width: 200px; height: 10px;" class="bar"></div>
<div style="display: block; margin: auto; background: grey; width: 200px; height: 100px;" class="firstElement">
    <div style="background: grey; width: 100px; height: 100px" class="secondElement"></div>
</div>
```

Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/3fkbwasg/

Thank you very much!